# Change size/alpha of markers in the legend box

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

What is the most convenient way to enlarge and set the `alpha` value of the markers (back to 1.0) in the legend box? I'm also happy with big coloured boxes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100000
s1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, n)
s2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.08, n)
ys = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

plt.plot(s1, ys, ',', label='data1', alpha=0.1)
plt.plot(s2, ys, ',', label='data2', alpha=0.1)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.005, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set legend symbol opacity with matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848808/set-legend-symbol-opacity-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use the `handler_map` option to `.legend()` to define a custom function to update the alpha or marker for all Line2D instances in the legend. This method has the advantage that it gets the legend markers correct first time, they do not need to be modified afterwards, and fixes issues where the original legend markers can sometimes still be seen.

This method makes use of [`HandlerLine2D`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerLine2D) from the [`matplotlib.legend_handler`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/legend_handler_api.html) module. I'm not aware of a way to do this without adding the extra import.

A complete script would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
import numpy as np

# Generate data
n = 100000
s1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, n)
s2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.08, n)
ys = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

# Create figure and plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(s1, ys, ',', label='data1', alpha=0.1)
ax.plot(s2, ys, ',', label='data2', alpha=0.1)

def change_alpha(handle, original):
    ''' Change the alpha and marker style of the legend handles '''
    handle.update_from(original)
    handle.set_alpha(1)
    handle.set_marker('.')

# Add the legend, and set the handler map to use the change_alpha function
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.005, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.,
          handler_map={plt.Line2D: HandlerLine2D(update_func=change_alpha)})

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

*Note, below is my original answer. I have left it here for posterity as is may work for some use cases, but has the problem that when you change the alpha and markers, it actually creates new instances on the legend, and does not remove the old ones, so both can still be visible. I would recommend the method above in most cases.*

If you name your `legend`, you can then iterate over the lines contained within it. For example:

```
leg=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.005, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

for l in leg.get_lines():
    l.set_alpha(1)
    l.set_marker('.')
```

note, you also have to set the marker again. I suggest setting it to `.` rather than `,` here, to make it a little more visible
[image]

Comment: This is great, but it doesn't actually update the marker. It seems to draw a new marker over the old one. Is there no way to actually access the marker itself?

Comment: Why markers are shown twice in the legend? is it possible to show the marker just once?

Comment: @user11696358 you can change that using the `numpoints` kwarg when you call `.legend()`

Comment: The old marker is still visible between the two new ones.

Comment: @Rainald62 you are correct. I have now updated my answer with a more robust method using a handler_map which corrects that issue

Answer (score 12):

```
leg = plt.legend()    
for lh in leg.legendHandles: 
    lh.set_alpha(1)
```

credit to https://izziswift.com/set-legend-symbol-opacity-with-matplotlib/

Comment: It's worth noting that URL has a date of 9 January, 2021, so is pretty recent. This solution also feels the most Python and "smells" right. ;-)

Comment: This has the issue that other answers have (my original answer included), that it is not updating the original legend handles, but rather adding new ones, so the old handles can still be seen in some cases.

Comment: Also the link in the answer is now dead

Answer (score 11):

For the size you can include the keyword `markerscale=##` in the call to legend and that will make the markers bigger (or smaller).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.clf()

x1,y1 = 4.*randn(10000), randn(10000)
x2,y2 = randn(10000), 4.*randn(10000)
ax = [fig.add_subplot(121+c) for c in range(2)]


ax[0].plot(x1, y1, 'bx',ms=.1,label='blue x')
ax[0].plot(x2, y2, 'r^',ms=.1,label='red ^')
ax[0].legend(loc='best')

ax[1].plot(x1, y1, 'bx',ms=.1,label='blue x')
ax[1].plot(x2, y2, 'r^',ms=.1,label='red ^')
ax[1].legend(loc='best', markerscale=40)
```

[image: The output from the code]

Answer (score 4):

for me the trick was to use the right property:

```
leg = axs.legend()

for l in leg.get_lines():
    l._legmarker.set_markersize(6)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll update my code, this looks the be the proper way ;)

Comment: if one needs to access _ variables, it arguably hardly the proper way - but it works :D

Comment: Even if it uses protected variables imho this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Another option: instead of altering your legend's markers, you can make a custom legend ([ref the matplotlib legend tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html))

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import numpy as np

n = 100000
s1 = np.random.normal(0, 0.05, n)
s2 = np.random.normal(0, 0.08, n)
ys = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

plt.plot(s1, ys, ',', label='data1', alpha=0.1)
plt.plot(s2, ys, ',', label='data2', alpha=0.1)

# manually generate legend
handles, labels = plt.axes().get_legend_handles_labels()
patches = [Patch(color=handle.get_color(), label=label) for handle, label in zip(handles, labels)]
plt.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.005, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., frameon=False)
```

[image: example]