# Modifying the Patch in the legend leaving alone the Patch in the scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can change the opacity of an item in the legend of a scatter plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# note the alpha value            vvvvvvvvvv
plt.scatter(range(10), range(10), alpha=0.15, label='Mount Resegone')
plt.scatter(range(10), [0]*10,    alpha=0.15, label='Rimini Beach')
plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[0][0].set_alpha(1.0)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

but doing that I change also the opacity of every dot in the scatter plot.

I guess that there is a single instance of the Patch, correct me if I'm wrong, but my issue is changing the Patch in the legend leaving alone the Patch in the scatter plot.

[image]

---

**Addendum**

---

The solution originally suggested (`handle._legmarker.set_alpha(1)`) does not work in recent Matplotlib, raising an AttributeError

```
'PathCollection' object has no attribute '_legmarker'
```

Fortunately it's even easier to have the expected behaviour

```
plt.scatter(range(10), range(10), alpha=0.15, label='Mount Resegone')
plt.scatter(range(10), [0]*10, alpha=0.15, label='Rimini Beach')
plt.legend().legendHandles[0].set_alpha(1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output look like?

Comment: @Pythoncoder `plt.scatter(range(10), range(10), alpha=` **0.15** `, label='Mount Resegone')`

Comment: @Pythoncoder I have added to my question a plot showing the expected output. Unfortunately I had to wait for a correct answer to be able to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You can just do:

```
leg = plt.legend()
leg.legendHandles[0].set_alpha(1)
```

Taken from: [Set legend symbol opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848808/set-legend-symbol-opacity)

> UPDATED: There is an easier way! First, assign your legend to a variable when you >create it:
>
> ```
> leg = plt.legend()
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> for lh in leg.legendHandles: 
>    lh.set_alpha(1)
> ```
>
> OR if the above doesn't work (you may be using an older version of matplotlib):
>
> ```
> for lh in leg.legendHandles: 
>    lh._legmarker.set_alpha(1)
> ```
>
> to make your markers opaque for a plt.plot or a plt.scatter, respectively.
>
> Note that using simply lh.set_alpha(1) on a plt.plot will make the lines in your legend opaque rather than the markers. You should be able to adapt these two possibilities for the other plot types.

Comment: This work for older Matplotlib's versions, now I have an Attribute Error, `'PathCollection' object has no attribute '_legmarker'`